# Fastest form of downloading using sockets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

Hi 
I have TCP/IP client server application. i want to send large serialized object around 1MB through sockets.
Is it possible to get better performance by splitting byte array to for example 10 chunks of arrays and open a socket for each and send them Async compared to opening one socket and send all large data through it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this doesn't speed up the transfer under normal conditions, it only adds overhead. It would only help if you have a slow network segment which is quite busy otherwise and the traffic is shaped per TCP connection.

Make sure that your sockets code is efficient, because wrong buffer and therefore packet sizes, synchroneous operation and other stuff may slow the transfer down.

Answer (score 4):

Splitting the data to less than the MTU will introduce more overhead as there will be more packets - this will actually slow things down. What you are proposing is already being done as part of the protocol i.e. splitting and re-assembling. I would experiment with sending less data e.g. compression.